# Is there a way to assign variables in __init__ without having them run immediately?

Tags: python, tkinter

So I was trying to write a program that converts various metric units to other units. (i.e. Cm to Mm) My Professor was adamant about not using `global`s and having all of our code be in either a function or a class. With the code as shown below, it gives me a:

```
ValueError  (*line 18, in __init__ self.intNtry = int(self.ntryAnswer) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''*)
```

Is there any way to have the variables not activate as soon as the program starts? I'm new to programming, please don't bully me

```
class Converter(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.txt = tk.Text(self, height=1, width=45)
        self.txt1 = tk.Text(self, height=1, width=45)
        self.txt2 = tk.Text(self, height=1, width=45)
        self.txt3 = tk.Text(self, height=3, width=45)

        self.unit1 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.unit2 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.num1 = tk.Entry(self)

        self.btn = tk.Button(self, text="Calculate", padx=15, pady=15, command=self.buttonClick)

        **self.ntryAnswer = self.num1.get()
        self.intNtry = int(self.ntryAnswer)**

        self.initWindow()

    def buttonClick(self):
        if self.unit1 == "cm" and self.unit2 == "m":
            ans1 = float(self.intNtry) / 100
            print(ans1)
```

Comment: `self.inNtry` shouldn't exist at all. Just call `self.num1.get()` inside `buttonClick`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class doesn't need an `intNTry` attribute. The value returned by `self.num1.get()` isn't interesting until you are ready for it, namely when you actually click the button.

```
class Converter(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.txt = tk.Text(self, height=1, width=45)
        self.txt1 = tk.Text(self, height=1, width=45)
        self.txt2 = tk.Text(self, height=1, width=45)
        self.txt3 = tk.Text(self, height=3, width=45)

        self.unit1 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.unit2 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.num1 = tk.Entry(self)

        self.btn = tk.Button(self, text="Calculate", padx=15, pady=15, command=self.buttonClick)

        self.initWindow()

    def buttonClick(self):
        if self.unit1 == "cm" and self.unit2 == "m":
            answer = self.num1.get()
            entry = int(answer)
            ans1 = entry / 100
            print(ans1)
```

If there are multiple places where it would be interesting to retrieve the value (or if you just want to use more encapsulation), a property as [suggested by @modesitt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61489711/1126841) would be appropriate.

```
class Converter(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.txt = tk.Text(self, height=1, width=45)
        self.txt1 = tk.Text(self, height=1, width=45)
        self.txt2 = tk.Text(self, height=1, width=45)
        self.txt3 = tk.Text(self, height=3, width=45)

        self.unit1 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.unit2 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.num1 = tk.Entry(self)

        self.btn = tk.Button(self, text="Calculate", padx=15, pady=15, command=self.buttonClick)

        self.initWindow()

    @property
    def field1(self):
        return int(self.num.get()) / 100

    def buttonClick(self):
        if self.unit1 == "cm" and self.unit2 == "m":
            print(self.field1)
```

Comment: OP should accept this answer - it explains what you should actually be doing better.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`property`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property)

```
class Converter(Frame):
    ...
    @property
    def intNtry(self):
        ntryAnswer = self.num1.get()
        return int(self.ntryAnswer)
```

which will dynamically evaluate when `.intNtry` is called. There is no reason to store this variable though - `.self.num.get()` can be called when you need the value during `buttonClick`. In general though, computed properties should use `@property`.

Answer (score 0):

You could always assign that variable to None and then create an additional method which sets it:

```
def __init__(self, parent):
   self.intNtry = None

def foo(self):
   self.intNtry = int(self.ntryAnswer)
```